# Can we explicitly compute this "shift"-quantity over Boolean functions $u:\mathbb{F}_2^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-fields, computer-science, boolean-algebras

This question is a follow-up of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417477/are-there-functions-mathbbf-2n-to-mathbbf-2-satisfying-these-special-r).

Let $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ be the field with two elements, and suppose that $n$ is odd.

**Question:** Can we compute the exact minimum $$A:=
\min_{u:\mathbb{F}_2^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2} \sum_{a\neq 0}\left(\sum_{x}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}\right)^2 \, \,?
$$

Here is a lower bound, which I don't know if can attained (see derivation below):

$$
A \ge \max\{1,\frac{f^2(n)}{2^n-1}\},
$$
where
$$
f(n):=\min \{\,\, |k| \,\,\, | \,\,\, k+2^n \,\,\,\text{is a square of an integer}\}.
$$

**Motivation:** This question arose while I was trying to [derive a lower bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395191/every-boolean-function-is-multiplicative-with-probability-greater-than-1-2) on the approximate multiplicativity of Boolean functions.

---

**Lower bound derivation:**

Set $s(x,a)=(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}$, $g(a):=\sum_xs(x,a)$, $r=\sum_{a \neq 0} g(a)$.

Since $g(0)=2^n$,
$$
\tag{1}
\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a}}[s(x,a)]=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum_a g(a)=\frac{2^n+r}{2^{2n}}.
$$

Now, we also have
\begin{equation*}
\tag{2}
\left(\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[(-1)^{u(\mathbf{x})}]\right)^2=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[(-1)^{u(\mathbf{x})}]\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{y}}[(-1)^{u(\mathbf{y})}]=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}[(-1)^{u(\mathbf{x})+u(\mathbf{y})}]=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a}}[(-1)^{u(\mathbf{x})+u(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a})}]=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a}}[s(x,a)],
\end{equation*}

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[(-1)^{u(\mathbf{x})}]$ is an integer multiple of $1/2^n$, so we may write
$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}[(-1)^{u(\mathbf{x})}]=\frac{m}{2^n}$.

Combining this with equations $(1),(2)$, we get
$$
\frac{2^n+r}{2^{2n}}=\frac{m^2}{2^{2n}},
$$
or
$$
2^n+r=m^2.
$$
Thus
$|r| \ge f(n)$, by the definition of $f$.

Now using Cauchy-Schwartz:
$$
f(n) \le |r| = |\sum_{a \neq 0} g(a)| \le \sum_{a \neq 0} |g(a)| \le \sqrt{\sum_{a \neq 0} g^2(a)}\sqrt{2^n-1}.
$$

---

Equality happens when all the $g(a)=t \in \mathbb{Z}$, and so $$
f(n)=|r|=|\sum_{a \neq 0} g(a)|=(2^n-1)|t|$$

Since $f(n) \le 2^n$, this implies
$$
(2^n-1)|t| \le 2^n,
$$
so $|t|=1$. Is it possible that indeed $|g(a)|=1$ for every $a \neq 0$?

Comment: what's answer for $n=1,3,5$?

Comment: Restatement: Discrete Fourier analysis on $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ allows us to write $(-1)^{u(x)} = \sum_{v \in \mathbb{F}_2^n} a_v (-1)^{\langle v,x \rangle}$ where $a_v$ is the Fourier transform of $(-1)^{u(x)}$. Orthogonality of $x \mapsto (-1)^{\langle v,x\rangle}$ allows us to eventually write your sum $\sum_{a \neq 0}(\cdots)^2$ as $2^{3n} \left( \sum_{v \in \mathbb{F}_2^n} a_v^4 - 2^n\right)$, so you want to minimize the Fourth moment of the Fourier transform of a function assuming the values $\pm 1$. By Plancheral, $\sum_{v} a_v^2 = 2^n$, and by C-S, $\sum_{v} a_v^4 \ge 2^n$.

Comment: If $A,B$ are abelian groups and $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a function, then define $$NB_{f}=\sum_{a\in A,a\neq 0}\sum_{b\in B}(f^{-1}[\{b\}]-\frac{|A|}{|B|})^{2}.$$ The quantity $NB_{f}$ as studied in the 2007 paper Nonlinearities of S-boxes by Claude Carlet and Cunsheng Ding, and $$NB_{u}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a\in\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n},a\neq 0}\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}.$$

Comment: @mathworker21 That is a good question. And indeed should be easy to program and check for small values of $n$...(If my programming skills were not so close to nonexistent).

Comment: Is not $f(n)^2<2^n-1$ for all $n>1$?

Comment: Experimentally, $A(1)=4$, $A(3)=64$, $A(5)=640$, $A(7)=17920$

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment:**

A function $u:\mathbb{F}_q^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q^n$ is *perfect nonlinear* if the derivative
$$
D_au(x)=u(x+a)-u(x)
$$
takes on each value in $\mathbb{F}_q^m$ equally often for any $a\neq 0,$ as $x$ ranges over the domain. Note that here $n$ is odd, $q=2,$ and $m=1.$ In which case we have
$$
D_au(x)=u(x+a)+u(x)
$$

Fix $a,$ and note that for each $x,$ $D_a(x)=D_a(x+a)$ in even characteristic. So we cannot have PN (Perfect Nonlinear) mappings here, but only so called almost PN (APN) mappings [which are 2-to-1].

A natural technique to obtain a function $u:\mathbb{F}_q^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q$ is to use the absolute trace.

Under this approach, a number of monomial power permutations have been shown to be APN and their composition with the absolute trace have also been used.

For example, for $q=2,$ the Gold exponent over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ is defined as
$$
x\mapsto x^{2^k+1}
$$
with $\gcd(2^k+1,n)=1,$ and $n$ odd. So take $u=tr(x^{2^k+1})$ and fix some basis to view $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ as $\mathbb{F}_2^n,$ then it turns out that
$$
u(x+a)+u(x)
$$ is balanced for all $a \in \mathbb{F}_2^n\setminus \mathbb{F}_2.$ this will yield
$$
\sum_{a\neq 0}\left(\sum_{x}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}\right)^2=
\left(\sum_{x}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+1)}\right)^2=2^{2n}.
$$
So your minimum is upperbounded by this quantity. I don't know of any other examples which give a lower minimum. Perhaps you can do a search and see for small $n$.